# jQuery Array with Data tags and print to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an unordered list of items with values appended as Data tags to each of the list items. When the user selects an item from the list, the li fades, the Data tags are printed into a table as separate cells, and all data is stored into an array. I was able to append each item to another list, but I am having difficult adding as a table row.

I believe it is the use of 'append' but, the li just gets added within table and with the current order of adding to the array, the data gets compounded.

I feel that the order needs to be click > add to array > then print to table.

[Here is a link to my most recent.](http://jsfiddle.net/benblustey/x22UP/)

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

```
var myArraySelected = [] ;

$(function() {

var myFunc = function() {
    myArraySelected = [] ;
    var userList = $('#selected');
    userList.children('li').each(function() {
        var userID = $(this).attr('data-user');
        var userService = $(this).attr('data-role');
        var userCategory = $(this).attr('data-category');
        var userName = $(this).attr('data-name');
        myArraySelected.push({
            'id':userID,
            'name':userName,
            'role':userService,
            'category' :userCategory
        });

    });
};

$('#userList li').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() { // code to run after the fadeOut
        $(this).append('<tr><td><p>'+ $(this).attr('data-name') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-user') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-role') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-category') + '</p></td></tr>')
        $(this).appendTo('#selected').fadeIn('slow');
        myFunc();
    });

});
myFunc();
});
```

Comment: Sorry but what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I am assuming that you are trying to append the clicked list-item's data to a table element. Currently you are appending to the list-item and then appending the list item to a table. How about just appending the table row onto the table without using the list-item.

Change:

```
    $(this).append('<tr><td><p>'+ $(this).attr('data-name') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-user') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-role') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-category') + '</p></td></tr>')
    $(this).appendTo('#selected').fadeIn('slow');
```

To:

```
    $('#selected').append('<tr><td><p>'+ $(this).attr('data-name') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-user') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-role') + '<br>' + $(this).attr('data-category') + '</p></td></tr>').find('tr:last').fadeIn();
```

And then to add to your array all you need to do is `push` another index onto the array right in the same place in your code:

```
$('#userList li').click(function() {

    //cache the `$(this)` selector since it will be used more than once
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut('slow', function() { // code to run after the fadeOut

        //append a row onto the `#selected` table using the clicked list-item's data-attributes as data; notice after the append I select the newly appended table row and fade it in (which assumes that it's CSS is making it hidden at first)
        $('#selected').append('<tr><td><p>'+ $this.attr('data-name') + '<br>' + $this.attr('data-user') + '<br>' + $this.attr('data-role') + '<br>' + $this.attr('data-category') + '</p></td></tr>').find('tr:last').fadeIn();

        //now push a new index onto the `MyArraySelceted` array using the data-attributes for the clicked list-item as data
        myArraySelected.push({
            'id'       : $this.attr('data-user'),
            'name'     : $this.attr('data-name'),
            'role'     : $this.attr('data-role'),
            'category' : $this.attr('data-category')
        });

        //now remove the list-item from the UL element
        $this.fadeOut(function () {
            $this.remove();
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Printing the values in the table worked fine, but the values for the array were not entered. I'm guessing it needs to go in "click > add to array > then print to table" order...

Comment: @benblustey If `#selected` is a table then searching for children `li` elements won't work. And if `#selected` is a table then you are creating invalid HTML by appending list-items to the table. And a side-note, when you search for table rows in a table don't use `.children()`, use `.find()` because most browsers add a `<tbody>` as the direct child of the `<table>` element and the `<tr>` elements are direct children of the `<tbody>` element since that is the proper way to mark-up a table.

Comment: @benblustey I would like to see a live version of your site if possible or if you could setup a jsfiddle. It seems like you may need some general advise.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much, I was stuck for awhile there. Let me set something up in jsfiddle.

Comment: I just created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benblustey/W8UdH/1/) with your changes. I am just getting into jQuery/JS, so thank you for your guidance.